# Converting utf-8 encoded to string from user input in python

Tags: python, input, utf-8

```py
a = '\xe6\xb8\xac\xe8\xa9\xa6'
print(bytes(a, 'latin-1').decode('utf-8'))

a = input("input:")
print(bytes(a, 'latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
```

The first one can print out the result correctly
While the second one will just print out the string I entered


output:

```
測試
input:\xe6\xb8\xac\xe8\xa9\xa6
\xe6\xb8\xac\xe8\xa9\xa6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What is your question? Note that escape sequences are only interpreted for string *literals*, i.e. those in the source code, not strings read from ``input``, files, or similar. (That's actually exactly what your code is already showing, just wanted to point it out in case it wasn't obvious to you.)

Comment: how do i parse the string from input in the same way as the first one does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation is a bit tricky:

```
# Use r'', simulate input
a = r'\xe6\xb8\xac\xe8\xa9\xa6'

print(a.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
```

Follow the transformation:

```
# Step 0 (initial)
print(a)
\xe6\xb8\xac\xe8\xa9\xa6

# Step 1
print(a.encode('ascii'))
b'\\xe6\\xb8\\xac\\xe8\\xa9\\xa6'

# Step 2
print(a.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape'))
æ¸¬è©¦

# Step 3
print(a.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1'))
b'\xe6\xb8\xac\xe8\xa9\xa6'

# Step 4 (final)
print(a.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
測試
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use this simpler method (at least if you are not worried about security risks):

```py
unicode_input = eval('"' + input() + '"')
```

Keep in mind: using eval has high security risks

or as suggested by @MisterMiyagi:

```py
import ast
unicode_input = ast.literal_eval('"' + input() + '"')
```

Comment: ``ast.literal_eval`` works just as well here, without the security issues.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi didn't know about that, good to know. updated my answer to include this